# Unity2D. Can't access my audio from another class.

Tags: c#, audio, 2d, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D platformer game on Unity and I have a script called PlayerController which I attached it to my player, and in it I have an array of audio clips.

```
 // audio 
 public AudioClip[] audioClip = new AudioClip[3];
 private AudioClip sound;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAyJ1.jpg)

And I have a getter which can access the specific audio clips inside the array.

```
 public AudioClip getSound(int clip)
 {

     if(clip == 0)
     {
         sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioClip[0];
         return sound;
     }
     else if(clip == 1)
     {
             sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioClip[1];
             return sound;
         }
         else if(clip == 2)
         {
             sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = audioClip[2];
             return sound;
         }

         return sound;   
  }
```

It works well when I use that getter inside my playercontroller class:

```
   GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = getSound(1);
   GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
```

However, I cant access it from another class:

```
     // audio
 private PlayerController audio;
 private AudioClip clip;
     if(other.tag == "Player")
     {
         HealthManager.HurtPlayer(damageToGive);
         //soundEffect.Play();

         clip = audio.getSound(2);

         GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = clip;
         GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

         Debug.Log("play");
     }
```

Why is this so?? Thanks!

Comment: Are these classes in the same script?

If not, are the scripts on the same game object?

Comment: No they are not on the same script nor on the same game object. The audio array in on the player but I am trying to access it in the enemy script! @JackLeahy

Answer (score 0):

In your second class you declare and initialize the player controller.

```
private PlayerController audio;
```

Then you try to get the audio clip form the PlayerController audio clip array like this:

```
clip = audio.getSound(2);
```

The Problem here is how unity works (component based system). 
You assign the audio clips from the inspector to the PlayerController script on the gameobject the script was assigned to. The Problem now is that you try instantiate a new class using the line:

```
private PlayerController audio;
```

This new audio object has a empty array because you didn't assign the audio clips inside the class. So there is no audio clip to receive.

One Solution for this to work would be to get a reference to the game object the script is one. if you want to keep the variable still private than you could do something like this:

```
audio = GameObject.Find(nameofthegameobjectthescriptison).getComponent<PlayerController>();
```

Then you can reference the "filled" array of the gameobject script using

```
audio.getSound(2);
```

Hope this helps and you understand what i was trying to say :)

Comment: Thankyou! Yes i understand :D

Comment: if my answer helped you, i would appreciate it when you mark it as best answer